# Range of integers imposed by the C++ standard

Tags: c++

This question is about what the C++ standard imposes to the range of the fundamental integer types. In the C++17 standard, the point `6.9.1` on fundamental types has a point `4` where it says that:

> Unsigned integers shall obey to the laws of arithmetic modulo `2^n`
>   where `n` is the number of bits in the value representation of that
>   particular size of integer.

In the C standard, it only says that if `[0, max]` is the range that can be represented by an unsigned integer, all operations that goes out of this range is reduced modulo `range + 1`. It never says that `range + 1` should be a power of 2.

Does this quote of the C++ standard means that all unsigned integers have a range of the kind `[0, 2^n - 1]` ? Can we infer from that point that all signed integers have a range of the form `[-2^(n/2), 2^(n/2) - 1]`?

I see nothing in the standard that say that, but the previous quote of the standard seems to imply that kind of things.

---

PS: This question is different from the one which is given here as a duplicate. The question linked is about why two's complement is not enforced in the standard. My question is about what is in the actual standard.

Comment: There is nothing in the stadard for signed types which is why wrapping round a signed integer is undefined behavior.

Comment: Your quote is only about unsigned integers, so I don't see how you end up with your first conclusion (bullet)? As for the second one, I don't see how having unsigned having range `[0, 2^n-1]` being related with two's complement here?

Comment: @Holt: I have corrected my question. Thanks.

Comment: [C **does** require that unsigned integer types have a range from 0 to 2^n-1 for some n.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2p1)

Answer (score 2):

I'll try an answer here, open for corrections:

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

This implies that the ranges of unsigned integers are `[0, 2^n - 1]`, I don't see how you could enforce this otherwise.

[[basic.fundamental]#3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-3) — Emphasis is mine

> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type: “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long int”, and “unsigned long long int”, each of which occupies **the same amount of storage** and has the same alignment requirements as the corresponding signed integer type; that is, each signed integer type has the same object representation as its corresponding unsigned integer type. [...]
>   **The range of non-negative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type**, **the representation of the same value in each of the two types is the same**, and the value representation of each corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the same. [...]

As far as I know, these are the only constraints linking signed and unsigned integers:

- first point is that related unsigned and signed integers are represented using the same number of bits `n`;
- second point is that any positive value of a signed integer has the same representation in the related unsigned type.

The three following methods of representing signed integers fullfil these constraints: [Sign & Amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation), [Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

As I read it, there are not enough constraints in  the standard to enforce two's complement representation for signed integers.